# OAuthMiddleware: the 'AuthenticationScheme' option must be provided

Tags: asp.net-core

everyone!

I am trying to implement OpenIDDict with ASP.NET Core in order to secure my Web API. However, after I followed the instructions from the OpenIDDict github page, I encountered the following error from the browser:

> ArgumentException: **The 'AuthenticationScheme' option must be provided.**
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthMiddleware..ctor(RequestDelegate next, IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, UrlEncoder encoder, IOptions sharedOptions, IOptions options)

Development environment and software version:

1. Visual Studio 2017
2. DB: SQL Server with .NET Core Identity database
3. .NET Core version 1.1.0
4. OpenIDDict version: 1.0.0-beta2-0612

Do you guys have any ideas about this error?

My AuthorizationController.cs file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Extensions;
using AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Primitives;
using AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server;
using AuthorizationServer.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using OpenIddict.Core;

namespace AuthorizationServer.Controllers
{
    public class AuthorizationController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IOptions<IdentityOptions> _identityOptions;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public AuthorizationController(
            IOptions<IdentityOptions> identityOptions,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _identityOptions = identityOptions;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [HttpPost("~/connect/token"), Produces("application/json")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Exchange(OpenIdConnectRequest request)
        {
            Debug.Assert(request.IsTokenRequest(),
                "The OpenIddict binder for ASP.NET Core MVC is not registered. " +
                "Make sure services.AddOpenIddict().AddMvcBinders() is correctly called.");

            if (request.IsPasswordGrantType())
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.Username);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
                    {
                        Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                        ErrorDescription = "The username/password couple is invalid."
                    });
                }

                // Ensure the user is allowed to sign in.
                if (!await _signInManager.CanSignInAsync(user))
                {
                    return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
                    {
                        Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                        ErrorDescription = "The specified user is not allowed to sign in."
                    });
                }

                // Reject the token request if two-factor authentication has been enabled by the user.
                if (_userManager.SupportsUserTwoFactor && await _userManager.GetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(user))
                {
                    return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
                    {
                        Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                        ErrorDescription = "The specified user is not allowed to sign in."
                    });
                }

                // Ensure the user is not already locked out.
                if (_userManager.SupportsUserLockout && await _userManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user))
                {
                    return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
                    {
                        Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                        ErrorDescription = "The username/password couple is invalid."
                    });
                }

                // Ensure the password is valid.
                if (!await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, request.Password))
                {
                    if (_userManager.SupportsUserLockout)
                    {
                        await _userManager.AccessFailedAsync(user);
                    }

                    return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
                    {
                        Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                        ErrorDescription = "The username/password couple is invalid."
                    });
                }

                if (_userManager.SupportsUserLockout)
                {
                    await _userManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user);
                }

                // Create a new authentication ticket.
                var ticket = await CreateTicketAsync(request, user);

                return SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties, ticket.AuthenticationScheme);
            }

            return BadRequest(new OpenIdConnectResponse
            {
                Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.UnsupportedGrantType,
                ErrorDescription = "The specified grant type is not supported."
            });
        }

        private async Task<AuthenticationTicket> CreateTicketAsync(OpenIdConnectRequest request, ApplicationUser user)
        {
            // Create a new ClaimsPrincipal containing the claims that
            // will be used to create an id_token, a token or a code.
            var principal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);

            // Create a new authentication ticket holding the user identity.
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal,
                new AuthenticationProperties(),
                OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            // Set the list of scopes granted to the client application.
            ticket.SetScopes(new[]
            {
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OpenId,
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Email,
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile,
                OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles
            }.Intersect(request.GetScopes()));

            ticket.SetResources("resource-server");

            // Note: by default, claims are NOT automatically included in the access and identity tokens.
            // To allow OpenIddict to serialize them, you must attach them a destination, that specifies
            // whether they should be included in access tokens, in identity tokens or in both.

            foreach (var claim in ticket.Principal.Claims)
            {
                // Never include the security stamp in the access and identity tokens, as it's a secret value.
                if (claim.Type == _identityOptions.Value.ClaimsIdentity.SecurityStampClaimType)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var destinations = new List<string>
                {
                    OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken
                };

                // Only add the iterated claim to the id_token if the corresponding scope was granted to the client application.
                // The other claims will only be added to the access_token, which is encrypted when using the default format.
                if ((claim.Type == OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name && ticket.HasScope(OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile)) ||
                    (claim.Type == OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Email && ticket.HasScope(OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Email)) ||
                    (claim.Type == OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role && ticket.HasScope(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Roles)))
                {
                    destinations.Add(OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken);
                }

                claim.SetDestinations(destinations);
            }

            return ticket;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it literally tells you... You need to pass an option for which Authenticationscheme to use... Show us the code where you create the Dict

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Milney. What do you mean by "where you create the Dict"?

Comment: AT some point you need to create an identity, something like;
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name,
                OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role);

Comment: I found those settings in the project "AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Samples" but not the "OpenIDDict".

Comment: I guess I have better enclosed my AuthorizationController.cs file as above to let you know more about the issue.

Comment: This is likely not an OpenIddict issue as the stack trace indicates that the exception is thrown from `OAuthMiddleware`'s constructor. This middleware serves as the base class for most the social providers in ASP.NET Core (e.g Facebook or Google), so make sure your configuration in Startup is correct. Don't hesitate to post it so people can help you find what's wrong.

Comment: You are right, Pinpoint. May I ask is there any conflict between social providers package and OpenIdDict? I tried either social providers/openiddict alone and it works but not at the same time.

Comment: OpenIddict should work just fine with the other authentication middleware, including the social providers using the OAuth2 generic middleware (we have a test of two asserting this integration, BTW).